# Send action/method upstream from an object to Wrapper class in java

Tags: java, object, oop

So lets say I have an array of Objects, lets call them `bankAccounts`, and the array is stored in a wrapper class, `Bank`. Lets say some other class calls a method in `Bank` that adds and subtracts money from the account. What I'm wondering is what the best way to have the bankAccounts themselves operate on the array they are stored in based on the money they have. Is there a way to cleanly have the affected object essentially tell the wrapper class to do some action it like remove it from the array or replace it? 
I can only think of every time an action is done on an object in the array, the wrapper class goes through and checks if anything needs to be done or have it such that I pass the wrapper class to the objects in the array and have the object call a wrapper class method. Is there a better way of doing this since these both feel like violation of oop? I was thinking something with lambdas but I'm not that well versed with them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ^ Theoretical question so no code to provide